# Logs in ListView? Memory issues? Alternative methods

Tags: android, listview, logging

I want to have an activity that shows the logs for the application. When it checks the internet for updates, how many updates it makes, etc etc.

So I'm thinking that there should be a new log entry every minute or so. What's the best way to display a long log like this? ListView? I plan to truncate the logs after...1000 entries? but still I don't want my app wasting tons of memory storing 1000 logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the complexity of your logs (one cell per entry might actually be a bit overkill)
you could try and store logs in a sqlite database, then use a simplecursoradapter and bind it to a listview. You wouldn't have memory problems as from the database perspective it's just text, and the cursor + adapter combination would make sure you only load and keep in memory what you're currently displaying on screen.

Comment: If I'm not doing 1 cell per entry, what's a better way to accomplish this? Also if I use the cursor + adapter approach even if you scroll the entire way down, wouldn't the previous entries still be part of the cursor? I was originally thinking db->hashmap->adapter. Would that be the same as cursor->adapter? Or does having the hashmap suck up memory?

Comment: so yea, any thoughts on this ^?